# Color strokes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs6, stroke, borders

I have made a path in Photoshop and I created a shape. The shape has a dashed stroke. I want to paint every dash in an other color. How can I do that?

I tried changing the stroke color but I can only set or 1 color or a gradient. But I would like to change every 50px or so in an other color. Can someone tell me how to do that? Can I paint them, or should I create a new layer?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna do that, but how? ;) Should I change a second layer and paint it in the right colors and give it  'Overlay', or?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, because I was going to write up a more detailed answer.  This is probably a project better suited for Illustrator, but if you need to do it in PS, it can be done, it's just more of a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I take a look to Illustrator. Could you perhaps help me a little bit in the right direction with Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, a task better suited for AI, but this is how I would do this in PS.  There may be a better way to go about this, but I don't use PS for this kind of stuff, so I don't know about it, if there is.

The initial shape:

[image]

I made a duplicate of the shape and decreased the Fill to 0%.  This is the shape that I then applied my stroke to.  I then selected every other dash with the Marquee Selection Tool.

[image]

With the selection still made, I created a Layer Mask, by clicking the icon at the bottom of the layers palette that looks like a Japanese flag.  I duplicated the layer with the mask on it and then inverted the mask by clicking on the mask in the layers palette and hitting CTRL+I or CMD+I.  This gives me two masked stroke layers, each showing the inverse regions of the other.

[image]

You can then recolor the strokes of these two layers the same as you would for the shape in the first place.

[image]

There may be better ways to accomplish this in PS, but like I said, I personally use AI for this kind of thing.  PS is limited with its shape and stroke options.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm working in Illustrator now but I can't get it work in Illustrator too. Again, only the gradients, but not an option to paint a part of a stroke...:S

Comment: I found the solution! http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-stroke-shape-adobe-illustrator-27751.html But many thanks for the help!

Comment: In AI, you would need to use the Expand Appearance command, to convert the strokes to objects then recolor them.